# Using keywords as object key throws syntax error in Aptana

Tags: javascript, aptana

I've got a problem with Aptana studio when trying to use objects that assign to 'with':

```
var x = {};
x.with = 12;
```

This produces Syntax Error: unexpected token 'with'

The code is in an external library which I'm using so I'd rather not change the code, which doesn't cause errors in IE or Chrome.

I've tried using Preferences > Javascript Syntax Validator and adding a rule, but I'm having trouble writing a correct expression. Does anyone know of a way to turn this error off without ignoring other 'with' occurrences that are genuinely misplaced?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could always do x['with'] instead...

Answer (score 4):

> This produces Syntax Error: unexpected token 'with'

That's because it *was* a syntax error, for a long time: It's a syntax error per the ES3 spec (1999), and probably was prior to that; as of ES5 (~2009; there was no ES4), it's no longer a syntax error, but some engines still in widespread use predate that spec and haven't been (and probably won't be) updated (IE8's, for instance).

`with` is a keyword. That expression (`x.with`) is a *property accessor*, specifically one using a literal property name. The ES3 definition of those required that the name be an *Identifier*, *Identifier* being a term the spec gives a specific definition of: Basically it's a name following certain naming rules that is not a reserved word. So `with` can't be used as an *Identifier*. To access a property with a name that's a reserved word, you have to use the bracketed notation with a string:

```
x["with"] = 12;
```

As of ES5, the rules for literal property names ([§11.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)) were relaxed. *(Many thanks to Felix Kling for pointing this out!)* Now, they just have to be *IdentifierName*, not *Identifier*. The difference? An *IdentifierName* is something that fits the naming rules; an *Identifier* is an *IdentifierName* that isn't a reserved word. This is covered in [§7.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).

**Wow** is that not something I would rely on JavaScript implementers and tool builders, etc., universally getting right if I were writing a library.

I think your only recourse is to open a bug report with Aptana and, for now, modify the library as described below. Not ideal.

---

More on the `[]` notation I touched on earlier:

```
x["with"] = 12;
```

In JavaScript, you can access properties either using dotted notation and a literal property name (`x.foo`), or using bracketed notation and a *string* property name (`x["foo"]`). When using a literal, the rules discussed above apply. When using a *string*, though, you can do just about anything you want (including spaces and another characters not allowed in *IdentifierNames*).

It works in object initializers, too:

```
var x = {
    "with": 12
};
```

That's what I'd use if I were writing a library, or any code that needed to run in the wild. Someday we'll be able to assume ES5 compatibility, but that day hasn't come yet.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. Neither Chrome nor Firefox throw errors. A property name can be any valid identifier name, reserved keywords are not excluded. See http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1, http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5 and http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.

Comment: @FelixKling: Well I'll be! You're right, it says so right there in [§11.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) and [§7.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6). *Edit* LOL! You were editing your comment as I was looking this up and replying! :-)

Comment: @Andreas: LOL! So you're not familiar with the whole `with` controversy! :-) Yes, it's a reserved word. In fact, it's an active keyword. `var o = {x: 15}; with (o) { console.log(x); }` logs `15` to the console. It's one of the least-used parts of JavaScript, not least because it's very hard to tell what's going on. In fact, it's so poorly-regarded that it's disabled in ES5's strict mode.

Comment: You're welcome! I agree with you anyway. Even if it is valid according to the spec, I would not rely on it to work in every environment.

Comment: It **was** a syntax error in EcmaScript 3. It works in all modern environments.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes indeed, I was surprised by the way I'd left that. I've updated it, thanks.